# How to config mybatis properties when accessing mysql via ssh tunnel

Tags: mysql, mybatis, ssh-tunnel

I want to connect to mysql via ssh tunnel, but I find that I don't know how to config mybatis properties. It seems like mybatis properties requires direct url? Like

```
jdbc:mysql://ip:port/database
```

Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

When you establish an SSH tunnel, your client sees just a port on the local box (or wichever box). It doesn't realize it's just a proxy, and treats it like any other port.

Therefore, there is no difference for MyBatis, or for JDBC. Just test the port using your preferred JDBC tool (I use SQuirrel SQL Client) to check the port is alive and responding, and then try it out with MyBatis.

If it still doesn't work, please post which specific error you are encountering.

Just a note. I find SSH tunnels somewhat flaky. They tend to break easy for me. Well.. maybe just my experience.